# Obtener resultado global de una lista de elementos c#

Tags: c#, array, api, lista

Me gustaría saber cómo obtener un resultado global a partir de una Lista de valores obtenidos de un string sql -> BD.

Con un `foreach()` no puedo porque recorre 1 a 1, y yo lo que quiero es que tenga en cuenta los 3 elementos que hay en mi lista para así poder devolver un resultado global de esos 3 elementos.

```
public static void Estado(List<Inumerable<TipoDocumento>> lista) //aquí en el método le traigo la lista de elementos obtenida
{
    foreach (var z in lista)
    {
        if(lista == .....)
        ..... Con esto no puedo porque me sacaría un resultado individual porque va recorriendo 1 a 1 en el foreach
    }
}
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo poder solucionarlo?

Comment: que criterio par filtrar vas a utilizar?

Comment: Podria utilizar el SelectMany de Linq de esa manera proyecta la lista en una sola y de esta manera hacer el filtrado o búsqueda que requiera

Comment: Y cuando tenga ya en una sola lista los valores, que ejemplo tiene 3 elementos, como puedo saber si dentro de esos 3 elementos("a", "y", "u"), existen 2 elementos concretos la "a"  y la  "u" ?gracias

Comment: Es importante comentar que criterio de seas usar como dice L. Ronquillo para realizar una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Sí puedes utilizar un foreach para lo que deseas. Podría ser algo así:

```
//Creamos una nueva lista que contendrá sólo lo filtrado
List<Inumerable<TipoDocumento>> listaFiltrada= new List<Inumerable<TipoDocumento>>();
//Recorremos
foreach (var z in lista)

{
    //si corresponde a la búsqueda, añadimos a la nueva lista
    if(z== .....){
        listaFiltrada.Add(z);
    }
    
}
//retornamos
return listaFiltrada;
```

Así, tendrías tus elementos filtrados en una sola lista.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Cuando ya tuviera esa ListaFiltrada con por ejemplo esto = "a","c","y", como podría saber si  de esos 3 valores se encuentran 2 variables o más, con 1 sabría pero si hay 2 o más elementos que quiero encontrar en ListaFiltrada? y si puedo saber eso, ya podría asignarle un resultado global,

Comment: quieres saber cuántos elementos tiene la lista? lo puedes saber utilizando el método `Length` de la lista. `listaFiltrada.Length`

Comment: mm no, me refería a que cuando tenga ya en una sola listaFiltrada con los valores, que ejemplo tiene 3 elementos, como puedo saber si dentro de esos 3 elementos("a", "y", "u"), existen 2 elementos concretos la "a" y la "u" ? o si por el contrario no existen

Comment: tendrías que compararlos específicamente, podría ser con `linq`

Comment: @Eneada, dime si ya resolviste

Answer (score 0):

aún no he resuelto el problema, para ser más específica, tengo esto:

{

```
       internal static void Estado(IEnumerable<TipoCodigo> lista) 

    {


        foreach (var z in lista)
        {
            if (z.Any(c => c.Codigo == "00325CH" || c.Codigo == "00358CH" ))
            {
                EstadoI = CalcularEstado.Ins;
            }
            else if (z.Any(c => c.Codigo == "00347CH" || c.Codigo == "00410CH"))
            {
                EstadoI = CalcularEstado.Escritura;
            }
                      ..........

        }
```

Pero tengo el problema de que no sé como obtener EstadoI que es un resultado global de esa  lista, y en el foreach recorre 1 a 1, y me gustaría ver como puedo convertir esa Lista de matrices que me llega en una lista de una sola matriz, e ir comparando la lista entrante con lo que hay en los if, y sacar un estadoI, teniendo en cuenta todos los elementos de la lista entrante